# Are there advanced keyboard shortcuts for Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar, keyboard-shortcuts

I like to do most of my stuff using the keyboard. On Gmail, this works quite nicely, but on Google Calendar, some keyboard shortcuts are missing.

For example, I'd like to browse days by using the <kbd>←</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd> keys, to actually navigate in the calendar itself:

[image]

Or, I'd like to be able to create an event on the selected day by pressing another key. The way it currently is, I always have to switch to the mouse to select the day first.

Is it possible to do this – probably with a userscript? I haven't found anything related.

Answer (score 2):

[J and K](http://lifehacker.com/370133/essential-google-calendar-keyboard-shortcuts) to move backwards and forwards through time (like Gmail and Google Reader).

Also check out the basic keyboard [shortcuts](http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=37034) for Google Calendar.

Answer (score 1):

Visual navigation is not supported currently (see all supported keys [here](http://www.google.com/support/calendar/bin/answer.py?answer=37034)), but to create an event, type <kbd>c</kbd> or <kbd>q</kbd> for a "quick" add, where you can type date and time as a sentence (i.e. "Meeting Bill Gates on Oct. 21 at 1pm In Seattle Cafe").

Answer (score 0):

Hit <kbd>a</kbd>, then you will view your Google Calendar in Agenda view through which you can tab and control specific calendar entries by hitting <kbd>enter</kbd> or <kbd>return</kbd>.

You can also use your navigational <kbd>up</kbd>, <kbd>down</kbd>, <kbd>right</kbd> and <kbd>left</kbd> arrows to navigate through the agenda view.  That is the best solution I have found for navigating to a specific entry.

Comment: None of these navigation keys except for `a` appear to function, at least on Windows Chrome.