# Google Calendar keyboard shortcut to select specific week?

Tags: google-calendar, keyboard-shortcuts

I navigate in Google Calendar using the keyboard shortcuts as much as possible.

If the month view is active, is there a keyboard way to select a **specific** week before switching to the week view (using the <kbd>w</kbd> shortcut)?

(This question is a bit related to [Are there advanced keyboard shortcuts for Google Calendar?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/19759/are-there-advanced-keyboard-shortcuts-for-google-calendar), but there's no real affirmative answer to that question.)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you simply select it *after* switching to week view, using <kbd>j</kbd> / <kbd>k</kbd> shortcuts?

Comment: The 'problem' is that if you switch to week view from month view, I have to figure out again where I am in the month. Doesn't take ages, but still would be easier if I could select the week before switching to month view.